# Loop through array from Elastic script Params

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-painless

I'm creating a (ElasticSearch) Painless script. And as parameter I'm setting an array, but I'm not able to loop trough that array in my script.

Elastic params setter (with NEST):

```
Params = new Dictionary<string, object>
             {
               { "ages", new []{2,4,6}},
             }
```

Painless script:

```
for(int age in params.ages)
{
 // do something
}
```

Error:

```
"script_stack": [
                    "... for(int age in params.ages){ ...",
                    "                ^---- HERE"
                ],
```

How can I use the param as an array?

Comment: Did you have a look at the documentation? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/master/painless-walkthrough.html#_accessing_doc_values_from_painless  They seem to use a full for loop to iterate through the items in an array.

OR 

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/master/painless-statements.html#_for

Comment: @Qpirate Yes, that seems to work indeed. So I think for params you must use the full for loop and with document properties it's not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to change your loop definition from

```
for(int age in params.ages)
```

to

```
for(age in params.ages)
```

Hope that helps.